# Mostrar 5 ul li's por fila y centrados horizontalmente

Tags: html, css, scss

Intento hacer una tabla de precios en HTML y CSS, donde también se muestran iconos de aplicaciones móviles.

Intento lograr esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son 5 iconos por fila, todos centrados.

Ahora mismo tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado tener solo 5 iconos por fila y que las siguientes filas, se muestren centradas horizontalmente.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6384u1o/

```css
.plan-item {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.plan-container .plan-item {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.plan-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.free-apps-container {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 22px;
  text-align: center;

  h6 {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  ul {
    height: 144px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 6px 4px;
    float: left;
  }

  ul li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: both;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="plan-container">

  <div class="plan-item">

    <div class="free-apps-container">
      <h6>Center</h6>
      <ul>
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
        <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-whatsapp-icon-121-thumb.png" width="22" height="22" />
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

He intentado utilizar flexbox pero no he logrado alguna diferencia. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que te parece si le haces un "container", aplicas un width al container y dejas que flex los acomode segun un porcentaje? Para 5 items, el % seria 20%.

```css
@import url("https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css");

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul li i {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="icon-group">
    <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Para validar, para dar espacio entre filas y no esten tan pegados, puedo colocar en el `ul li` un `margin-bottom: 6px;` o existe alguna forma mejor de indicar el espaciado?

Comment: puedes agregarle margin, o hacer un height fijo y dejar margin auto en los iconos

Comment: Curiosidad, cómo sabes que para 5 items el % seria 20%? no se cómo sacar dicho cálculo, podrías agregarlo a tu respuesta? sería de mucha ayuda

Comment: 100% dividido entre 5 igual a 20%

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar grid en lugar de flexbox. El modelo **grid** es como las tables pero con vitaminas.

```
<style>
.grid-caja {      
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(5,100px);
     grid-gap: 6px;
     padding:15px;
     justify-items:center;
}
</style>
```

Y en el HTML tendrías

```
<div class="grid-caja">
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Para responsive puedes redefinir la clase, auqneu si lo que vas a poner con imágnes pequeñas lo mismo no lo necesitas.
Espero que te solucione el problema.
**EDITO**
Para centrar en cada celda usa justify-items: center
**EDITO**
Solución con flex

```
.flex{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 120px;
justify-content: center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

en lugar de grid-caja usa esta clase. El ancho es función del ancho de cada imagen como son de 22 pues 5x22 son 120px.
Puedes usar justify-content: center, space-around o space-evenly. Prueba el que más te guste y si queires espacio entre las imçagnes dale algo más de los 120px.
En el flex no son necesarios los divs vacíos.
Coge la que más te guste

Comment: En la clase `grid-caja `he usado `justify-content: center` para centrar todo dentro del div, pero, los items del grid no he podido centrarlos. [Ver demo](https://ibb.co/0rfknjq).

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta, tienes que usar justify-items: center. El justify-content se refiere al grid completo respecto de su contenedor. el nombre engaña un poco.

Comment: Extraño pero con justify-items tampoco funciona. Ejemplo, mi fila es de 5 items y la ultima fila solo tiene 3 items, quisiera que esto 3 items de la ultima fila se vean centrados en el medio (horizontalmente). Tal vez no es posible con grid? No estoy seguro.

Comment: Justify items te debe centrar las celdas. Si quieres los tres sobrantes centrados podrías que dejar libres las dos celdas laterales de la tercera fila, es decir, divs vacios en los laterales y las tres centrales llenas. Si no se centran por alguna extraña razoón por los divs con text-align:center

Comment: Mira si es [esto lo que necesitas](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/grid2x5.htm). He dado un ancho a la caja para que se vea mejor.

Comment: Correcto, ese es el efecto que quiero, pero, veo que hay que colocar divs vacíos a los laterales. En mi caso, la lista de iconos (la cantidad) viene de forma dinámica (backend) y no se qué cantidad tendrá la última fila para colocar a la izquierda o a la derecha divs vacíos. Creo que esto me introduce cierta complejidad solo para el efecto de centrar los últimos. De igual forma aprecio mucho tu apoyo, aprendí el uso de grid el cual desconocía.

Comment: He editado y he añadido la opción con flex, prueba ambas y así comparas.